# Do Ruby classes get cleared out between Rake tasks

Tags: ruby, rspec, rake

I have a Rakefile that defines the spec task as

```
task :spec => [:check_dependencies, :load_backends]
```

And then runs the actual rspec tests.  During the load_backends task, it loads a class called `Story`, but in the first spec test, `defined?(Story)` returns false.

I'm assuming that it is intended behavior of Rake to start with a fresh environment at the beginning of each task, but is there a way to override this?  Or do I need to re-architect loading the backends into each task?

Comment: Well, my rake knowledge is thin, but Rails has a task 'environment' that loads the Rails environment once depended upon. Therefor, I don't believe rake is cleaning up, but something else must be off.

Comment: can you post the code in the :load_backend task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RSpec's spec task fires up a new Ruby process (mainly to not screw with your Rake process, I think), therefore classes defined in a rake task (even the spec task) are not available in your specs. Consider moving this logic to your spec helper or don't use RSpec's spec task.